# Windows 10: apply theme programmatically

Tags: command-line, windows-10

is there any way in Windows 10 to apply a given .theme or .themepack file by using the command line (programmatically)?
In Windows 7 I could use something like this: `rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:"C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\aero.theme"` but in Windows 10 this opens another dialog.

Also, is there any way to change the desktop wallpaper from the command line in Windows 10?

Answer (score 4):

You can execute your theme file directly:

> x:\>path to your theme file.theme

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question while looking to do the same thing for my company's computer image. The command below worked well for me, keep in mind that the `taskkill` part would kill all settings windows

`C:\PATH\TO\THEME\FILE.theme & timeout /t 03 /nobreak > NUL & taskkill /f /im systemsettings.exe`

This will launch the theme file which will apply the theme but also open the Setting app/window, but then it will wait for the timeout (set to 3 seconds in the command above) then kill the Settings app/window.

Tested on Windows 10 Enterprise x64 v1909. Also depending on the performance of the computers you might be able to lower the timeout from 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

if you found this question looking for a way to toggle between Light/Dark modes in Windows 10 *without changing your theme* then [this answer in the "Win 10 forums"](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24038-change-default-app-windows-mode-light-dark-theme-windows-10-a.html) explains how to do it with powershell:

Light *App* Mode

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 1 -Type Dword -Force
```

Dark *App* Mode

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 0 -Type Dword -Force
```

Light *OS* Mode

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name SystemUsesLightTheme -Value 1 -Type Dword -Force
```

Dark *OS* Mode

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name SystemUsesLightTheme -Value 0 -Type Dword -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a custom theme, they are located in the "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes" folder.
Run the following command in the command line, substituting the theme file to the one you want to use:

```
"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\my_theme.theme"
```

Or, to do it at startup (like I am doing as for some reason since an update my computer likes to remove my nice theme when it boots up), pop a batch file (which I called set_theme.bat) with the same command in it into the startup folder to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Say you have 2 themes you wish to switch between.
In my case, a 'dark' theme and a 'lite' theme.

1. I open notepad and place the full path to the location of my 'dark' theme and   save the notepad file as 'DARK_theme.bat'.
2. I open notepad and place the full path to the location of my 'lite' theme and save the notepad file as 'LITE_theme.bat'.
3. Double clicking these .bat files will switch desktop theme to the specified within the .bat files.

The entry between the curly braces, is the contents of 'DARK_theme.bat'
{"C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\hcblack.theme"}

The entry between the curly braces, is the contents of 'LITE_theme.bat'
{C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\aero.theme}

Comment: This answer does not directly answer the original post: the question asks how to accomplish this from the command line.

Answer (score -1):

```
C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\hcblack.theme
```

Use this as BAT.. **100% Working...**

Comment: Change the path if using a custom theme, eg. "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\my_theme.theme"